# Chrome web server extension - running an app locally

Tags: google-chrome-extension, localhost

I am looking to use Web Server for Chrome extension only for the localhost in order to run an app:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en

It's easier for me to use this Chrome add on rather than installing Python or XAMPP.

Is it possible to run an app locally this way. If you want to test pages built with Angular, is it possible this way also.

Thanks